# Group delta response with 'select member' returns null for members

Tags: sharepoint-online, query, microsoft-graph

I am trying to sync members of a 365 Group but in the delta query I am getting null value in members. I am following the guide from Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-groups?tabs=csharp#initial-request). To quote from that guide: "..such as when users are added or removed from groups.". That is exactly what I am trying to do. This is the code I am using:

```
Microsoft.Graph.Groups.Delta.DeltaResponse deltaResponse;

deltaResponse = Task.Run(() => graphClient.Groups.Delta.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
{
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = $"id eq '{groupId}'";
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "id", "members" };
    
})).Result;

deltaResults.GraphGroupItems.AddRange(deltaResponse.Value.Select(x => new GraphGroupDTO()
{
    Id = x.Id,
    Members = x.Members?.Select(member => new GraphDirectoryObjectDTO() { Id = member.Id }).ToList(),
    Owners = x.Owners?.Select(owner => new GraphDirectoryObjectDTO() { Id = owner.Id }).ToList(),
}));
```

I have double checked that there are members in the group that I run this code on.
For some reason the deltaResponse has null in Members property. Does someone see what I am doing wrong here?